# How many cells can I store in google spreadsheets?

Tags: java, google-sheets

I am writing a java program that stores and reads data from a google spreadsheet. I am wondering if anyone has an experience with the performance limitations and the data size limitations of this, like, how many cells can I store in the spreadsheet before the API doesn't allow me to add any new cells? and is there a number of cells after which the API becomes too slow and performance becomes a problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Spreadsheets: Up to 5 million cells for spreadsheets that are created in or converted to Google Sheets.](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/37603?hl=en)

Complexity is also a factor as the sheet may just time out. From [Jeff Herb](http://instructionaltechtalk.com/google-drive-file-size-limits/):

> Google shares a few formulas that specifically contribute to the complexity of your sheet, they are the following:
>
> - VLOOKUP, QUERY, SUMIF, and similar formulas that take a large range
>     of cells as input.
> - Volatile formulas (for example, NOW, RAND, OFFSET, INDIRECT) are
>     recalculated every time the spreadsheet is modified. If there are a
>     large number of formulas that depend on cells with volatile formulas,
>     they will be recalculated on each edit, which may slow down a
>     spreadsheet.
> - Import-based formulas (e.g., IMPORTRANGE) are recalculated
>     periodically and increase complexity.